# Android Sliding Drawer slow in changing selected item

Tags: java, android, slidingdrawer

I am trying to implement a feature where when I click on an item in the Android Sliding drawer, the item that's clicked will have the color changed.

I don't know why, there is a half a second delay between button pressed and item changing color.

Any idea?

```
private void selectItem(final int position) {

        changeFragment(position);
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        if (position == 0 && dataStorageManager.loggedIn) // If user selects Home, Title will be equal to "Sort By"
        {
            setTitle(dataStorageManager.getDisplayName());
        }  // if not Home, than use string from mPageTitle Array
        else {
            setTitle(mPAGETitles[position]);
        }

        Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }           
        }, 10);

    }
```